# Converting a list of strings into one list in a string

Tags: python, string, list

What I'm trying to do is turn this

```
['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

into this:

```
['python']
```

Ok what if I want to make every list in this list a word

```
[['f', 'e', 'd'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']]
```

into this

```
[['fed'], ['def'], ['word']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
reduce(lambda a,b:a+b,['p','y','t','h','o','n'])
```

your probably going to fail this class :/ study hard padwan

```
y=[['f', 'e', 'd'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']]
map(lambda x:reduce(lambda a,b:a+b,x),y)
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but OP does require a list ;)

Comment: yeah :P you gave him that though so :P I figure thats all good :)

Answer (score 1):

As a general solution you can go this way:

```
lst = [['f', 'e', 'd'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']]
>>> map(''.join, lst)
['fed', 'def', 'word']
```

This will basically feed all the elements in the list one-by-one (sublists) into the function provided as the first argument to the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) built-in function, which is [`''.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is our case. As you can expect, it will provide a new list, that contains strings obtained by joining the sublists.

Comment: Ok what if I want to make every list in this list a word

Comment: @ChessRockwell checkout the update

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only a `for` loop, `list` and `string` methods:

```
>>> aList = [['f', 'e', 'd'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']]
>>> newList = []
>>> for X in aList:
...     newList.append("".join(X))
... 
>>> newList
['fed', 'def', 'word']
```